# Smallest free memory space in early space crafts equipped with a computer?

Tags: spacecraft, record, computer

Early space crafts used magnetic memory, semiconductor memory was not available. Memory size was very small, the program was written in assembler language. Programmers worked hard to fit all necessary functions in the limited memory space.

What was the smallest free memory space in early space crafts? The space left over after the program was in place. Different word sizes were used, so the number of free memory words please.

Of course only space crafts with a digital processor and memory for data and program.

Comment: You mean left over after the program was in place?

Comment: @SF. Yes, that is exactly what I mean, Any help to improve my wording is welcome. You surely noticed that English is not my first language.

Comment: It's not uncommon to devote all working memory not specifically used for something else to a call stack. At that point, all the memory is "used" in that it has an assigned purpose. Apart from that, unless someone can find a mention of some system that was documented to use every single word of memory, I don't think this question is answerable...that's a really obscure detail that's likely to be mixed in with proprietary information, not something that's commonly known.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, I don't think the question is *meaningful*: most early spacecraft computers were Harvard architecture, not von Neumann.

Answer (score 2):

The record is hold by Voyager:

> The programmers must have done an outstanding
> job, considering the slow processor and limited memory. At launch,
> only two words of free space remained in the 4K of plated wire.

**Only two words of free space in a 4K memory, this record is unbeatable.**

Source: [*Computers in Spaceflight*](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19880069935), p. 178

Answer (score -2):

If I am reading wikipedia right the honor goes to explorer 1 with zero memory.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorer_1

Acording to the article the tape recorder was not ready so the science data was transmitted in real time.

Comment: I found this in your source: A total of 29 transistors were used in Explorer 1, plus additional ones in the Army's micrometeorite amplifier. So there was no digital processor at all in Explorer 1. A real processor would require many hundreds of discrete transistors. The question was about left over  digital memory.